# How to send a data class object from one module to another module?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, multi-module, data-class

I am using Android Navigation Component and a single Activity architecture. I want to send a data class object from module A to module B.

My **feed** module imports in **build.gradle** the **store_article** module.

The redirection from my **feed** module to my **store_article** module works.

My **feed_nav_graph.xml** looks something like this:

```
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/newsDetailFragment"
            android:name="news.feed.view.ui.NewsDetailFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news_detail">
        <argument
                android:name="article"
                app:argType="feed.model.Article" />
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_newsDetailFragment_to_storedArticleScreenFragment"
                app:destination="@id/storedArticleScreenFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/storedArticleScreenFragment"
            android:name="news.stored_article.view.ui.StoredArticleScreenFragment"
            android:label="Stored Articles"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_stored_article_screen">
        <argument
                android:name="article"
                app:argType=".core.Article" />
    </fragment>
```

How can I now access the data class object from my **store_article** module?

I can't do something like this `val args: StoredArticleScreenFragmentArgs by navArgs()` because I would had to import the **feed** module and this will lead to an cyclic dependency error.

```
class StoredArticleScreenFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution is to use the exact same fragment declaration with the argument in my **stored_articles_nav_graph.xml** from **stored_article** module.

The **stored_articles_nav_graph.xml** from **stored_article** module looks something like this:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/storedArticleScreenFragment"
            android:name="stored_article.view.ui.StoredArticleScreenFragment"
            android:label="Stored Articles"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_stored_article_screen">
        <argument
                android:name="article"
                app:argType=".core.Article" />
</fragment>
```

Now, I can call `navArgs()` to get the send Article object from the **feed** module.

```
class StoredArticleScreenFragment : Fragment() {

    private val args: StoredArticleScreenFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val article: Article = args.article
    }

}
```